# Getting 413 Error when calling Express Api from Swift

Tags: node.js, swift, express

When I try to access my Express endpoint that I made in node from my iOS app, I get a 413 error, saying that the payload is too large. Here is my Node code.

```
router.post('/images/tags/nutritionalInformation/image/base64encoded', function (req, res) {
    var base64Stream = req.body.imageString;
    var imgDecodedBuffer = decodeBase64Image(base64Stream);
    // write to image file
    var prefix = guid().toString() + ".jpg";
    var filePath = './uploads/' + prefix;


    return s3fsImpl.writeFile(prefix, imgDecodedBuffer.data).then(function () {
        var s3BaseUrl = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/app/" + prefix;
        console.log(s3BaseUrl);
        app.models.predict('KEY', s3BaseUrl).then(
            function (response) {
                var responseJson = JSON.stringify(response.data.outputs[0].data.concepts);
                var data = collectTags(responseJson);
                data.then(function (value) {
                    res.json(value);
                });
            },
            function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
    });
})
```

I tested this out in postman and when I attach the base64 encoded string in the body, it works fine! However, when I try to send a POST call from Swift using the following Code :

```
func getTags() {
        let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "burger.jpg")!
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
        // base64 encode imagedata
        let prefix = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"
        let strBase64:String = prefix + (imageData?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters))!

        // Call tagging api https://foodenodeapp.herokuapp.com/api/images/tags/nutritionalInformation/image/base64encoded
                var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://foodenodeapp.herokuapp.com/api/images/tags/nutritionalInformation/image/base64encoded")!)
                request.httpMethod = "POST"
                let poststring = "imageString=" + strBase64


                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                    guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                        print("error=\(error)")
                        return
                    }

                    if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                        print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                        print("response = \(response)")
                    }
                    print(data)
                    let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                    print("responseString = \(responseString)")
                }
                task.resume()
            }
```

However, when I print out the responseString in the Swift Code, I get this response:

```
nutritionalInformation/image/base64encoded } { status code: 413, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 18;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Sun, 04 Dec 2016 20:18:15 GMT";
    Server = Cowboy;
    Via = "1.1 vegur";
    "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
    "X-Powered-By" = Express;
} }
18 bytes
responseString = Optional("Payload Too Large\n")
```

So I did some research and I tried changing my `app.js`, which is my root file (the logic code is in `api.js`).

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true, limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.redirect('/api');
});

app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));
```

However, when after this change, when I run the function in Swift, I now get a 500 error.

Any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thought I fixed it but I didn't :(

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs from the server side.

If your server is `Node JS` then make changes as:-

```
    var express    = require('express')
   var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

   var app = express()
   app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb' })) // change limit according to you.
```

for other server change limit.